# How to handle a removeEventListener call that is calling itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript

I have an mousedown listener, that is designed to add two more listeners.

A mousemove listener, and a mouseup listener that removes all previously added listeners. They all look like so.

```
    startListeners = () => {
        var content = this.content;

        this.divider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.documentElement.className += ' dragging';
            document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', this.moveHandler, true);
            document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', this.upHandler, true);
        }, false);
    };

    moveHandler = (e: any): any => {
        var lastX = e.pageX;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var deltaX = e.pageX - lastX;
        lastX = e.pageX;
        this.leftPercent += deltaX / parseFloat(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(this.content).width) * 100;
        this.updateDivision();
    };

    upHandler = (e: any): any => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace(/\bdragging\b/, '');
        document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.moveHandler, true);
        document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.upHandler, true);
    };
```

I'm running into a problem where my mouseup handler is running the last-most line in it's code to execute. When it calls

```
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.upHandler, true);
```

The function I'm telling it to remove, "this.upHandler", gets executed, which I'm already in. Then it runs that line again, then it starts the same function over again, and keeps running in this loop over and over.

From what I thought I understood the only reason I reference the method this.upHandler in the removeEventListener method is so that the code knows which to remove.

Is it standard behaviour to execute the function I'm telling it to remove? If so what should I be doing so I can remove this function/event listener, but not keep calling the function that's doing the removing.

**Edit:** User squint had mentioned without a full example it is difficult to see what might be going on. I'm going to dump my controller below, and my html. I was attemping to get a fiddler running, but I couldn't get it to work for some reason, sorry about that.

Here's the Typescript

```
module assessor.fundraising {

    class DetailController {

        content = document.getElementById('content');
        left = document.getElementById('left');
        right = document.getElementById('right');
        divider = document.createElement('div');

        leftPercent = 50;

        static $inject: string[] = [];

        constructor() { }

        $onInit = () => {

            this.divider.id = 'divider';
            $(this.divider).css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'width': '5px',
                'margin-left': '-2px',
                'top': '0',
                'bottom': '0',
                'background': '#bbb',
                'border': '1px outset #bbb',
                'border-top': '0',
                'border-bottom': '0',
                'cursor': 'col-resize !important'
            });
            this.content.appendChild(this.divider);
            this.updateDivision();
            this.startListeners();

        };

        updateDivision = () => {
            this.divider.style.left = this.leftPercent + '%';
            this.left.style.width = this.leftPercent + '%';
            this.right.style.width = (100 - this.leftPercent) + '%';
        };

        startListeners = () => {
            this.divider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                document.documentElement.className += ' dragging';
                document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', this.moveHandler, true);
                document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', this.upHandler, true);
            }, false);
        };

        moveHandler = (e: any): any => {
            var lastX = e.pageX;
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            var deltaX = e.pageX - lastX;
            lastX = e.pageX;
            this.leftPercent += deltaX / parseFloat(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(this.content).width) * 100;
            this.updateDivision();
        };

        upHandler = (e: any): any => {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace(/\bdragging\b/, '');
            document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.moveHandler, true);
            document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.upHandler, true);
        };

    }

    angular.module('assessor.fundraising')
        .controller('assessorFundraisingDetailController', DetailController);
}
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="content" style="position: relative; height: 100%;">
    <div id="left" style="float: left;width: 50%;height: 100%;overflow: auto;background: #fee;">left</div>
    <div id="right" style="float: left;width: 50%;height: 100%;overflow: auto;background: #efe;">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hard to say without a complete example. I don't see anything that'll result in the behavior you describe given the information provided.

Comment: Dang, really? In the chrome debugger, basically what is happening is I enter my upHandler method. It executes each line at a time, and when it gets to that last removeEventListener statement, it goes and highlights the "mouseup" keyword, then it highlight the, "this.upHandler" then it jumps to the top of the upHandler function and runs the lines again until it hits the bottom, then goes to the top and runs it again.

Comment: I haven't used TypeScript and don't know what frameworks you may be using, but does `this.upHandler` get defined as a "getter"?

Comment: The upHandler function is meant to only run removeListener logic. When the user clicks on a single specific element on the page, a mousedown listener triggers. It will add two listeners. One that performs coordinate logic while the mouse is moving, and a second listener that is waiting for the mouse to be released via a mouseup event. When the mouse up event triggers the upHandler function is called and is supposed to remove the mousemove, and mouseup listeners that the mousedown listener had added. I'm sorry if that isn't helpful. I'm not sure how else to explain the process.

Comment: Yes, I understand the intended logic. What I mean is that `this.upHandler` should only invoke a function if `upHandler` was defined as a "getter" function. With a "getter", you don't need the `()` to invoke it. Try this: `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, "upHandler").get)`. Does it show you the function?